# Bitwise LINQ result to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-sql, bit-manipulation

I need to query a table using the bitwise operator to produce a dictionary result. I'm far from a pro when it comes to LINQ, I have the following:

```
    return (Dictionary<string, bool>) (from r in db.LocationVisibilities
                                       where (r.Code & (int) permissionLevel) != 0 //bitwise statement in where clause
                                       select new
                                                  {
                                                      r.Item, value = Boolean.Parse(r.Attribute.ToString())
                                                  });
```

Comment: You have that query, and it's doing...?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Mr. Skeet! I changed to the logic below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast a query to a dictionary like that, you can call the `ToDictionary` function instead and it will handle all the details for you.

```
var dict=
   (from r in db.LocationVisibilities
    where (r.Code & (int) permissionLevel) != 0 //bitwise statement in where clause
    select new {
      r.Item, value = Boolean.Parse(r.Attribute.ToString())
    }).ToDictionary(w=>w.Item, w=>w.value);
```